# Main query not querying any posts in custom taxonomy template

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, loop, templates

I have created a template for my custom taxonomy, `byron_community_cat`. I have named it `taxonomy-byron_community_cat.php`. My problem is, when using the default WordPress loop, it does not display any posts. I have created some posts and have added them to a term in this taxonomy. Below is my code for the post type and taxonomy.

```
/**
 * Registers the Community post type
 * @return void
 */
function byron_community_register()
{
    register_post_type('byron_community', [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => __('Community posts', 'byroncommunity'),
            'singular_name' => __('Community post', 'byroncommunity'),
        ],
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'menu_position' => 40,
        'taxonomies' => ['byron_community_cat'],
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
        'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'],
        'has_archive' => __('community', 'byroncommunity'),
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => __('community', 'byroncommunity'),
            'with_front' => false,
        ],
    ]);
}
add_action('init', 'byron_community_register');

/**
 * Registers the Community category taxonomy for the Community post type
 * @return void
 */
function byron_community_register_category()
{
    register_taxonomy('byron_community_cat', 'byron_community', [
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'community_category',
            'with_front' => false
        ]
    ]);
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('byron_community_cat', 'byron_community');
}
add_action('init', 'byron_community_register_category');
```

I use the default loop like this in my taxonomy template, yet, it does not display any posts:

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        //HTML stuff...
    }
}
```

The right template is being chosen, because changes outside the loop, are reflected on the page. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I suspect it might have something to do with the way I've registered the taxonomy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you flush your permalink setting? Btw you don't need to call this `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('byron_community_cat', 'byron_community');`, you already did this in CPT and taxonomy registration.

Comment: I did flush the permalinks. Thanks for the tip, I'll remove the line. I added it to be sure that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that when registering the post type, you've set `exclude_from_search` to true.

See this note from the [WordPress Coedex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type):

> Note: If you want to show the posts's list that are associated to taxonomy's terms, you must set exclude_from_search to false (ie : for call site_domaine/?taxonomy_slug=term_slug or site_domaine/taxonomy_slug/term_slug). If you set to true, on the taxonomy page (ex: taxonomy.php) WordPress will not find your posts and/or pagination will make 404 error...